# ValueError in ManyToManyField | Django

Tags: django, django-models

This is the model I am working with:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from products.models import Variation

class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart')
    items = models.ForeignKey(Variation)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.items.title


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, through='CartItem')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (str(self.id))
```

I had run `makemigrations` and `migrate` once before, with the `items` field in the model `Cart` being `items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem)`

Now after making this change, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot alter field carts.Cart.items into carts.Cart.items - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)
```

How do I fix this ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, you can't convert a many-to-many into a foreign key. You'll have to split this into two migrations: first, remove the original field completely and run makemigrations to create the DROP COLUMN call; then, add the foreign key and run makemigrations again to create the ADD COLUMN.